# jQuery works fine in dreamweaver but not in any browser. How to fix?

Tags: jquery

Im an absolute novice when it comes to using jQuery.  Im writing the code and testing it within dreamweaver.  It works perfectly until I attempt to run it within a browser.  The goal of the jQuery is to hide a `<div>`, append text to another `<div>` and show that `<div>`.  I have all my coding in a file named scripts.js.

The contents of this file are

```
$(document).ready(function() { //SignIn validation + content change

    $("#enter_email").hide();
    $("#enter_password").hide();
    $("#main2").hide();

    $("#signIn").click(function(event){
        var email = $("#Email").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        if(email == "" && password == "" )
            $("#enter_email").show().add("#enter_password").show(); 
        else if(email != "" && password == "")
            $("#enter_password").show();
        else if(email == "" && password != "" )
            $("#enter_email").show();
        else if(email == "admin" && password == "password")
            $("#login").hide().add("#register").hide().add("#displayUserName").text(', ' + email).add("#main2").show().remove("#register");
        else
        (overlay());
    }); 

    var now = new Date();
    var hours = now.getHours();
    var msg;
    if(hours<12)
        msg = "Good Morning";
    else if(hours<18)
        msg = "Good Afternoon";
    else
        msg = "Good Evening";
    $('#greeting').text(msg);


    //Control the look of selected catalog categories

    $(".shop-links1").click(function(){//Add category to selected
        $(".clear").show();
        $("#selected").show();
        $("#catalogNav1").hide();   
        $('div[class="shop-links1"]').add("#selected ul").append("<li><a class='selectedLinks' href=''>Category: " + $(this).text() + " </a></li>");        });

    $(".shop-links2").click(function(){//Add price to selected
        $(".clear").show();
        $("#selected").show();
        $("#catalogNav2").hide();   
        $('div[class="shop-links2"]').add("#selected ul").append("<li><a class='selectedLinks' href=''>Price: " + $(this).text() + " </a></li>");
        });

    $(".shop-links3").click(function(){//Add size to selected
        $(".clear").show();
        $("#selected").show();
        $("#catalogNav3").hide();   
        $('div[class="shop-links3"]').add("#selected ul").append("<li><a class='selectedLinks' href=''>Size: " + $(this).text() + " </a></li>");
        });

    $(".shop-links4").click(function(){//Add artist to selected
        $(".clear").show();
        $("#selected").show();
        $("#catalogNav4").hide();   
        $('div[class="shop-links4"]').add("#selected ul").append("<li><a class='selectedLinks' href=''>Artist: " + $(this).text() + "</a></li>");
        });

    $(".clear").click(function(){
        $(".clear").hide();
        $("#selected ul li:not(:first)").remove();
        $("#selected").hide();
        $("#catalogNav1").show();
        $("#catalogNav2").show();
        $("#catalogNav3").show();
        $("#catalogNav4").show();   
    });

    //Sort catalog

    $("#tops").click(function(){//Sort by tops
            $(".tops").show();
            $(".tunics").hide();
            $(".dresses").hide();
        });

        $("#tunics").click(function(){//Sort by tunics
            $(".tops").hide();
            $(".tunics").show();
            $(".dresses").hide();

        });

        $("#dresses").click(function(){//Sort by dresses
            $(".tops").hide();
            $(".tunics").hide();
            $(".dresses").show();
        });

});//End document.ready
```

The area under the comment "//Control the look of selected catalog categories" is what i am using to do this.

The HTML head is

```
<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/scripts.js"></script>

<!-- Unique title on each page to increase search engine optimisation.  Should always contain accurate information as well as some of the main focus areas. --> 
<title>Art on Fashion</title> 

<!-- Page description meta tag gives search engines a summary of what the page is about -->
<meta name="description" content="This site has been created and submitted in partial fulfilment of the BSc Hons Information and Communication Technologies course, it is a final year project that focuses on XHTML, PHP, JavaScript, SEO, MySQL, CSS and a Content Management System"/>

<link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>
```

Comment: Can you add the contents of the `<head></head>` tag from your html file please?

Comment: Have you tried debugging with your browser's console to see what error messages are being generated? Have you remembered to include jQuery and checked your paths?

Comment: http://scmweb.infj.ulst.ac.uk/~B00448232/com601/assignment_1/login.html

Comment: The link above is the html of the site.  I have checked the paths but i am not sure how to debug in safari

Comment: It works for me on your link. What is it supposed to do that its not?

Comment: When any of the links on the left (under category, price, size etc) are clicked it should remove the div of the selected link and append the link to another div at the top of that section.  If you run it in chrome and click one of the links you will see the desired action happen but it flashes on and then off straight away

Comment: Internet explorer gives this error when one of those links is clicked: (HTTP 403 Forbidden) means that Internet Explorer was able to connect to the website, but it does not have permission to view the webpage.

For more information about HTTP errors, see Help.

Comment: Sorry to waste your time guys but I found the error myself.  Thanks for the help though.  It turned out that the links on the left needed to be amended from:

a class="shop-links1" href="" id="tops"

To:

a class="shop-links1" href="#" id="tops"

I didn't know removing the hash tag would break this.

Thanks again!

Comment: I don't believe it's valid HTML to leave `href` empty.  If you're intercepting the default behavior, use `href="#"` and jQuery's `preventDefault()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<s>I don't believe it's valid HTML to leave the `href` empty.</s>  If you're using jQuery to intercept the default `click` behavior of an anchor tag, `<a>`, use `href="#"`.

Don't forget to put [jQuery's `preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) at the top of each `click` handler function, which will:

- prevent the page from jumping to the top,
- prevent the hash from being added to the URL,
- as well as prevent the hashed URL from being added to browsing history.

jQuery:

```
$(".shop-links2").click(function(event){
   event.preventdefault();
   // your click handler code
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="shop-links2 .....
```

Comment: It is valid html to lead off the `href` attribute, but that makes the tag a named anchor and not a hyperlink. (See [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.2))Browsers have different behaviors for each and named anchors generally don't get click event listeners. Dreamweaver must not differentiate.

Comment: @PatrickM, You are correct, it's still valid HTML and I updated my post accordingly.  However, leaving out `href` entirely causes issues with [how the cursor & text will display](http://jsfiddle.net/vArxR/2/).  And it's only an "anchor" when `<a href="#"></a>` is left empty... once you put some text between `<a href="#">link</a>`, it becomes a "hyperlink" (as long as it also has an `href`).  As far as anchor tags not getting `click` event listeners; you can attach a `click` event listener to anything you want... even a `div`.

Comment: I should've read my source more closely (and proofread my comment). We're splitting hairs here. They're all "anchor"s, that's what the `<a>` tag is called (unlike say, div, which has no official name or meaning). The cursor & text discrepancies is what I meant by making it a hyperlink. And for click event listeners, I didn't mean attached custom event listener, I meant the browser doesn't have do anything when you click on an `<a>` which has no href attribute (unless of course someone attached one), whereas an `<a>` with even `href="#"` triggers a response: you go to the top of the page.

Comment: @PatrickM, a `div` does have an official name; it's a "division" but we digress.  Yes, I know `<a>` is called an "anchor" element.  Clearly, I meant that when `<a>` has no content it can behave like an "anchor" and when it has content, it can behave as a "hyperlink"... as per the jsFiddle in my last comment.  No need to respond, this hair-splitting and horse-beating is done as far as I'm concerned.